# Popup's text box is not dissapearing after popup.isOpen = false

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, popup

I need following behavior: When I start typing in window little textbox appears with the first letter typed already in it, then after I typed text and press enter textbox should dissapear until I will type in that window again. The problem is when I set `Popup1.IsOpen = false` text box still remain in a window.

```
<Window x:Class="Beta.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown_1">  
  <Grid> 
    <Popup Name="Popup1" IsEnabled="True" IsOpen="False" VerticalOffset="-200" HorizontalOffset="50">
       <TextBox Name="tbx" Width="50" KeyDown="tbx_KeyDown" />
     </Popup>
  </Grid>
</Window>

string temp;

private void Window_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup1.IsOpen = true;
        tbx.Focus();
    }

private void tbx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Popup1.IsOpen = false;
            temp = tbx.Text;
            tbx.Text = null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I copied your code and it works fine. Maybe it would help if you paste also the code where you open the popup..

Comment: @rhe1980 Sorry I updated the code. It couldn't work fine it was not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sholud add e.Handled =true, so the Window_KeyDown_1 wont be raised and reopen the popup

```
   private void tbx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Popup1.IsOpen = false;
            temp = tbx.Text;
            tbx.Text = null;
            e.Handled = true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Window_KeyDown_1() method is called always. You have to set e.Handled=true

```
  private void tbx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
     {
        Popup1.IsOpen = false;
        temp = tbx.Text;
        tbx.Text = null;
        e.Handled = true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: sorry. user106419 was faster.. :-)